# Regular expression for domain validation

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression to validate the following domain types.

https://www.google.co.in

www.google.co.in

google.co.in

google.com

subdomain.domain.com

Regex should accept all these types.

Comment: Show the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to spend some thoughts on whether regular expresssions really are the tool of choice for your job. Domain names are subject to constraints which make regular expressions to match them kind of cumbersome (read as: a nightmare to maintain).

Having said this, try

```
^(https://)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+){1,2}$
```

Explanation:

- optional `https` scheme in front
- optional `www.` prefix
- each subdomain in domain names has at least 2 characters (not mandated by the standards but required by some registries for at least some subdomain levels)

Shortcomings:

- matches domain names with 2 or 3 segments only
- matches domains given by ip adresses only
- does not match all special chars permitted. in particular, does not properly exclude leading/trailing hyphens in subdomains
- length constraints not checked
- validity of top level domains not checked
- validity of ip address specifications not checked
- no advanced regex features

Suggestion:

Use a simpler expression to check for basic syntactic correctness:

```
^(http[s]?://)?([^.:/@#]+)(\.[^.:/@#]+)+$
```

Check the subtler constraints independently as needed. There is a subjective dimension to where to draw the separating line, of course.

Suggested reading:

All applicable RFCs. While these are fairly technical documents and often don't make an easy reading, the effort spent is worthwhile as these are the authoritative sources.

- [RFC 3696: Checking and Transformation of Names,Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696.txt)
- [RFC 2181: Clarifications to the DNS Specification, Section 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt)
- [RFC 1035: Domain Names, Section 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)

Comment: can you give me for jquery.. i'm using jquery validation-engine